# Incorporate public hollydays in a workday function

Tags: javascript, date

My need is to calculate how many work days I get between 2 dates. However I need to also do the public hollydays (Xmas, New Year, etc).

Actually This function work with the weekend but I can't find a way to do the same with he public hollydays. I just use javascript (so no moment.js). I try to test with writting all the public hollydays and soustract it if the 2 dates is between the hollydays, but I don't think it a good methode of processing like this.

Here's the function that a took from a topic in Stack Over flow :

```
dateDifference : function(start, end) {

              // Copy date objects so don't modify originals
              var s = new Date(+start);
              var e = new Date(+end);

              var jourdelan = new Date(end.getFullYear(),00,01);

              // Set time to midday to avoid dalight saving and browser quirks
              s.setHours(12,0,0,0);
              e.setHours(12,0,0,0);

              // Get the difference in whole days
              var totalDays = Math.round((e - s) / 8.64e7);

              // Get the difference in whole weeks
              var wholeWeeks = totalDays / 7 | 0;

              // Estimate business days as number of whole weeks * 5
              var days = wholeWeeks * 5; 

              if(jourdelan > start && jourdelan < end) { 
                    --days;
               }

              // If not even number of weeks, calc remaining weekend days
              if (totalDays % 7) {
                s.setDate(s.getDate() + wholeWeeks * 7);

                while (s < e) {
                  s.setDate(s.getDate() + 1);

                  // If day isn't a Sunday or Saturday or a public hollidays, add to business days
                  // && start.getDate() <= noel >= end.getDate()
                  if (s.getDay() != 0 && s.getDay() != 6) { 
                      ++days;
                  }
                }
              }
              return days;
            },
```

As u can maybe see I add a '--days' to test when the 2 dates is between a public hollydays. However (I live in France, and I don't know if in others countries you have the same thing) sometimes public hollydays like Monday Pentecost is not always the same day all years.

In France in *2019* it was the *09/06/2019*.

In *2020* it's the *31/05/2020*.

and in *2021* it's the *23/05/2021*.

Have you guys have any idea to do implements that rule and incorporate this hollydays rules in a better way ?

Comment: 1. Use a library that does it. 2. Fetch a list of public holidays from somewhere and use them during calculation 3. Look up the dates and hardcode them for the next 10 or so years. 4. Figure out an algorithm for when a given holiday would be and use it.

Comment: `sometimes public hollydays like Monday Pentecost is not always the same day all years` .. couldn't your holidays be in an array? @VLAZ where would be coding be in 20 years if everyone relied on a library?

Comment: @GetSet actually moving forward, instead of us having to re-invent the calendar for the billionth time.

Comment: @VLAZ tell that to assembly programmers. I get your point however, it wasn't missed. Same token isn't it fun to implement a solution even if research proves its already solved?

Comment: Can't really use a librairy. It's project for my company that I took to evolv it and not sure I can't use some. I dont see any librairy added on the project in JS

Comment: Dont know why you *cant* use a library or incorporate the code in your project

Comment: I can try but I'm a junior developper and never work with Javascript librairy. Have you got someting that explained how to add it in tje project and how it work for my issues ?

Comment: Btw it's a maven project, so i'm i bit lost with where and how to put js librairy ...